# BeautifulSoup output stays []

Tags: python, import, python-requests, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the texts from a website with BeautifulSoup + python requests. But it is only getting [] as an output.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "http://nos.nl/artikel/2093082-steeds-meer-nekklachten-bij-kinderen-door-gebruik-tablets.html"
r  = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "article_title"})

print data
```

output:

```
[]
```

I've tried;

```
> data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "article_title"}
> data = soup.find_all("div", class_="article_title") data =
> data = soup.find_all("div", class_="article")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that class exists on the site? Did you check the HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems:

- The tag used on the site is a `h1`, not a `div`.
- The class name is `article__title` (that's *two* underscores!).

So what you want, is:

```
data = soup.find_all("h1", {"class": "article__title"})
```

Which gives us:

```
[<h1 class="article__title">Steeds meer nekklachten bij kinderen door gebruik tablets</h1>]
```

I used my Firefox web inspector to quickly get this information, by the way ;-) Chrome, Internet Explorer, Safari, and all other browsers that I know have similar tools built-in. I strongly suggest you learn to use at least the basics of them, because it'll make your life a whole lot easier!

Comment: Damn I should have checked that first, sorry and thanks!

Comment: I want to save my content as a .txt file but I'm stuck again, could you maybe help me?

Comment: @Danisk If it's a different question, then you should ask a different question about it ;-) You should also mark this answer as accepted if it fixed your problem, by the way :-) That way other folk can see it already has a fix and I get points for it! (woohoo!)

Answer (score 0):

First problem is that there isn't a `article_title` tag in [the website](http://view-source:http://nos.nl/artikel/2093082-steeds-meer-nekklachten-bij-kinderen-door-gebruik-tablets.html). If you use `article__title` (two underscores) it will return something, because that is a tag. Look through the html source to see what tags actually exist!